# Problema usando IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql

Soy nuevo en esto,
estoy teniendo problemas para implementar el siguiente código dentro de un procedimiento almacenado:

Básicamente lo que busco es que compruebe si existe la tabla y si existe borra los datos y luego la tabla:

```
IF EXISTS (select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_name='WEB_SESSION_PH') 
    begin
      truncate table WEB_SESSION_PH
      drop table WEB_SESSION_PH
    end
```

Pero me da el error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (select TABLE_NAME from
>   information_schema.tables where TABLE_name='WE' at line 1 0.000 sec

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Comment: No te valdría con `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'WEB_SESSION_PH'`?

Comment: No, da el mismo error.

Comment: Perdona, el nombre de la tabla debe ir sin comillas: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WEB_SESSION_PH`. Prueba asi

Comment: Debería funcionar como dice @Pikoh, si colocas el nombre de la tabla sin las comillas... no necesitas el `SELECT...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF EXISTS]
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
    [RESTRICT | CASCADE]
```

[DROP TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) elimina una o más tablas. Debe tener el privilegio [DROP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop) para cada tabla.

¡Ten cuidado con esta afirmación! Elimina la definición de la tabla y todos los datos de la tabla. Para una tabla particionada, elimina permanentemente la definición de tabla, todas sus particiones y todos los datos almacenados en esas particiones. También elimina las definiciones de partición asociadas con la tabla descartada.

> **NOTA**
>
> A partir de MySQL 5.7.6, los archivos de definición de partición
>   (.par) ya no se crean para tablas InnoDB particionadas. En cambio, las
>   definiciones de partición se almacenan en el diccionario interno de
>   datos de InnoDB. Los archivos de definición de partición (.par) se
>   siguen utilizando para tablas MyISAM particionadas.

[DROP TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) causa una confirmación implícita, excepto cuando se usa con la palabra clave TEMPORARY. Vea la [Sección 13.3.3, "Declaraciones que causan un compromiso implícito"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

> **Importante**
>
> Cuando se descarta una tabla, los privilegios otorgados
>   específicamente para la tabla no se eliminan automáticamente. Deben
>   abandonarse manualmente. Ver [Sección 13.7.1.4, "Sintaxis de GRANT"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

Si no existen tablas nombradas en la lista de argumentos, la instrucción devuelve un error que indica por nombre qué tablas inexistentes no pudo eliminar, pero también descarta todas las tablas en la lista que sí existen.

Use IF EXISTS para evitar que ocurra un error para las tablas que no existen. En lugar de un error, se genera una NOTA para cada tabla inexistente; estas notas se pueden visualizar con [SHOW WARNINGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html). Consulte la [Sección 13.7.5.40, "MOSTRAR Sintaxis de ADVERTENCIAS"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html).

IF EXISTS también puede ser útil para eliminar tablas en circunstancias inusuales en las que hay un archivo .frm pero ninguna tabla administrada por el motor de almacenamiento. (Por ejemplo, si se produce una salida anormal del servidor después de eliminar la tabla del motor de almacenamiento pero antes de la eliminación del archivo .frm).

La palabra clave TEMPORARY tiene los siguientes efectos:

- La instrucción solo incluye tablas TEMPORALES.
- La declaración no causa una confirmación implícita.
- No se verifican los derechos de acceso. Una tabla TEMPORAL solo es
  visible con la sesión que la creó, por lo que no es necesaria ninguna
  verificación.

El uso de TEMPORARY es una buena forma de asegurarse de no caer accidentalmente en una tabla que no sea TEMPORARY.

Las palabras clave RESTRICT y CASCADE no hacen nada. Se les permite facilitar la transferencia desde otros sistemas de bases de datos.

[DROP TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) no es compatible con todas las configuraciones [innodb_force_recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_force_recovery). Consulte la [Sección 14.21.2, "Cómo forzar la recuperación de InnoDB"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html).

Comment: gracias.Estas tablas son temporales se borran al principio de procedimiento almacenado y luego se recrean a partir de otras tablas con los datos diarios.

Comment: @ekom77 me parece que las tablas temporales no hace falta borrarlas con DROP... a no ser que quieras utilizarlas varias veces en un mismo proceso. De lo contrario, la tabla se borra ella sola.

Comment: ME he expresado mal, no son tablas temporales si no tablas con datos temporales.
Estas tablas se utilizan para guardar  en tablas históricas los datos diarios  y posteriormente borrar  con seguridad de las tablas principales estos datos diarios( previamente guardados en las tablas históricas).